# Forward declaring a constexpr function in a header

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

Say I have the following files. Is this invalid C++ (linker chokes, so yeah) or is it a mistake in my syntax? Must a forward declaration of a constexpr function be in the same file as its definition?

**header.h**

```
extern constexpr int fun(int);
```

**source.cpp**

```
constexpr int fun(int x) 
{
    return x * 2; 
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver: Related, but different rules apply to functions vs classes.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is why I didn't actual vote.  The answer should work though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's wrong. [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) implies that the function is inline. Inline functions must be defined in every translation unit where it's used. If you include that header in a translation unit other than `source.cpp` and use the function, that translation unit lacks the definition.

So, the solution is to move the implementation to the header. No need to worry about multiple definition, since the function is inline.

It doesn't technically need to be in the same file, but because the definition must be in every file that uses the function, it's simplest to define it in the same header.

Comment: `extern inline` is fine, but it's `extern` is by default so superfluous.